# A well-known lemma of Brown?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, triangulated-categories

In the first section of the paper "Reconstruction of a variety from the derived category and groups of autoequivalences" of Bondal-Orlov ([arXiv:alg-geom/9712029](http://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9712029)), the "well-known Brown lemma" is referenced several times with the paper "Cohomology theories" of E.H. Brown cited.  I have heard of the Brown representability theorem which was proved in this paper, but I don't think this is the result being referenced by B-O.  Does anyone know which lemma is being referred to?

Comment: I haven't checked it thoroughly, but I think they are referring to the ideas in section 3 of Brown's paper. Since they seem to provide the necessary ideas to complete the proofs of the relevant propositions 1.2 and 1.3, I think this reference is more an attribution of ideas than a suggestion that you should go and look into Brown's paper for proofs.

Comment: Commenter: thanks, I thought that might be the case.  Is there any chance you know where one might be able to find the proofs (or at least the formal statements)?

Comment: Maybe section 8 of Keller's [Derived categories and their uses](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~keller/publ/dcu.pdf) for  contains the statements you're after, but I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for. Some of the proofs appear in section 6 of Keller's [Derived categories and universal problems](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~keller/publ/dcp.pdf) (lemmas 6.5 - 6.7).